# Zeebus Puzzle #10

Tags: rebus, music, movies, seasonal

My dreaming took a turn towards nostalgia last night...

[image: Zeebus Puzzle Image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based entirely on @Alex's answer, this could be

> a **white Christmas**, because 
> - the Braille letters for "christmas" are in white rather than black, 
> - the [music](/questions/tagged/music) tag indicates a reference to the song "[White Christmas](https://genius.com/Bing-crosby-white-christmas-lyrics)", whose opening line "I'm dreaming of a white christmas" echoes the sentiment in the opening line of the question and 
> - @S. M. points out that *White Christmas* is also [a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Christmas_(film)), explaining the [movie](/questions/tagged/movie) tag.

Comment: rot13(Naq Juvgr Puevfgznf vf nyfb n 1954 zbivr (jurer gur fbat pbzrf sebz), fb vg svgf obgu gntf.)

Comment: This is it! +1 to @Alex also for getting this going in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if it's all there is to get but:

> Christmas

Explanation:

> It is Braille alphabet but the dots are inverted (a dot means a blank in the actual alphabet, a blank means a dot)

Comment: This is close, there's something else to it.